# Poor performance from numba.prange

Tags: python, numba

I'm trying to put together a simple example to illustrate the benefits of using `numba.prange` for myself and some colleagues, but I'm unable to get a decent speedup. I coded up a simple 1D diffusion solver, which essentially loops over a long array, combining elements `i+1`, `i`, and `i-1`, and writing the results into element `i` of a second array. This should be a pretty perfect use case for a parallel for loop, similar to OpenMP in Fortran or C.

My complete example is included below:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, prange

@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def diffusion(Nt):
    alpha = 0.49
    x = np.linspace(0, 1, 10000000)
    # Initial condition
    C = 1/(0.25*np.sqrt(2*np.pi)) * np.exp(-0.5*((x-0.5)/0.25)**2)
    # Temporary work array
    C_ = np.zeros_like(C)
    # Loop over time (normal for-loop)
    for j in range(Nt):
        # Loop over array elements (space, parallel for-loop)
        for i in prange(1, len(C)-1):
            C_[i] = C[i] + alpha*(C[i+1] - 2*C[i] + C[i-1])
        C[:] = C_
    return C

# Run once to just-in-time compile
C = diffusion(1)

# Check timing
%timeit C = diffusion(100)
```

When running with `parallel=False`, this takes about 2 second, and with `parallel=True` it takes about 1.5 seconds. I'm running on a MacBook Pro with 4 physical cores, and Activity Monitor reports 100% and around 700% CPU usage with and without parallelisation.

I would have expected something closer to a factor 4 speedup. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: running your code, with ```parallel=False``` I get 1.52s, with ```parallel=True``` I get 524 ms and with ```parallel=True``` and changing the other range to prange, I get 326 ms

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Perhaps I should try rebooting my machine or something. BRB. (By the way, from the point of view of the diffusion solver, I'm not sure it's such a good idea to change the first range to prange, since each iteration depends on the complete previous iteration)

Comment: After a reboot I still get the same results on my Mac laptop, but when I try running on a linux desktop I see a more reasonable speedup. Strange. But thanks anyway, I guess that means there is nothing wrong with my code.

Comment: @Nin17 parallelizing the `Nt` loop should just result in wrong results due to a race conditions. Thus, this is not a good idea to do that in practice.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I'm aware of that it was more to show that using prange does improve performance over range

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be to avoid the temporary array. https://pastebin.com/Ps4bJqt0 This is, although single threaded, already faster than your parallel version. With some effort this is also parallelizeable, but without  further optimizations on cache usage it won't scale well due to memory bandwidth limitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The poor scalability certainly comes from the saturation of the RAM which is shared by all cores on a desktop machine. Indeed, **your code is memory-bound** and the memory throughput is pretty limited on modern machines compared to the computing power of CPUs (or GPUs). As a result, 1 or 2 cores are generally enough to saturate the RAM on most desktop machine (a bit more cores are needed on computing servers).

On a 10 core Intel Xeon processor with a 40~43 GiB/s RAM, the code takes 1.32 seconds in parallel and 2.56 seconds in sequential. This means only 2 times faster with 10 cores. That being said, the parallel loop read the full `C` array once per time step and also read+write the full `C_` array once per time step (x86 processors need to read the written memory by default due to the *write allocate cache policy*). The `C[:] = C_` does the same thing. This means `(2*3)*(8*10e6)*100/1024**3 = 44.7` GiB or RAM are read/written during only 1.32 second in parallel, resulting in a 33.9 GiB/s memory throughput reaching 80% of the RAM bandwidth (very good for this use-case).

To speed up this code, you need to read/write less data from/to RAM and compute data as much as possible in cache. The first thing to do is to use a **double-buffering** approach with two views so to avoid a very expensive copy. Another optimization is to try to do multiple time step in parallel at the same time. This is theoretically possible using a complex [**trapezoidal tiling strategy**](https://crd.lbl.gov/assets/pubs_presos/sirev09-stencil.pdf) but very tricky to implement in practice, especially in Numba. High-performance stencil libraries should do that for you. Such optimization should not only *improve the sequential execution but also the scalability* of the resulting parallel code.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, and extra thanks for the explicit calculation of memory read/write! I hadn't thought of trying to calculate that. Would you be able to add some suggestions or references of how to implement the double buffering you mention?

Comment: To implement the double buffering method, it turns out the simplest solution is to do `C_, C = C, C_` at the end of each time step (it swaps the reference of the array so it can be done very quickly in constant time). At the end of the function, you can return either `C` or `C_` regarding whether `Nt` is odd or even. This trick should make your code twice faster.

Comment: Oooh, that's neat. I hadn't thought of that. Upon checking, I find that with `C[:] = C_` the code is almost twice as fast as `C = C_`, but as you say, `C, C_ = C_, C` is quite a bit faster again. Thanks again, I've learnt several useful things today.

Comment: Be careful, `C = C_` certainly do not do what you think it does: it does not copy the array. In Python, (nearly) everything is a *reference*. `C = C_` causes the `C` to reference the object referenced by `C_` (ie. the array). Thus modifying `C` will modify `C_`  because both reference the same array. `C[:] = C_` causes a copy because `C[:]` is a view and the assignment on views works differently: it makes a copy of the array content. Using `C = C_` cause the source and destination to be the same and thus results to be wrong. The rule of thumb is to always check results ;) .

Comment: Ah, yes of course. Come to think of it I've scratched my head over strange results where that was the issue numerous times before.

Comment: @JérômeRichard am I missing something? replacing ```C[:] = C_``` with ```C_, C = C, C_``` gives a different result to the original, and having both makes it slower??

Comment: Ha! I forgot that your range did not start from 0. Thus, the first and last items are left unmodified and can come from the "bad" array. You need to copy the two border items from `C` in `C_`. This is a good example why above rule of thumb is so important :D !